Starting animation from AppWidget Android
I have a pulse animation which i need to run inside an AppWidget , I have already tried the animation in MainActivity and it works fine but when i move the same animation code to AppWidget , The AppWidget shows a message that it can't load Widget . is it possible to run animations inside AppWidget ? I would appreciate any help from you Thank you .

This is my code


class RippleWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {

   private var progress = 0
   private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
   private lateinit var remoteViews: RemoteViews
   private var rippleBackground: RippleBackground? = null

   @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout")
   override fun onUpdate(context: Context?, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager?, appWidgetIds: IntArray?) {
       super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)

       rippleBackground = RippleBackground(context)
       
       appWidgetIds?.forEach { widgetId ->
           remoteViews = RemoteViews(context!!.packageName, R.layout.ripple_widget_layout)

           appWidgetManager?.updateAppWidget(widgetId,remoteViews)
       }

       rippleBackground!!.startRippleAnimation()
       handler.post(updateProgressTask)
   }

   private val updateProgressTask = object : Runnable {
       override fun run() {
           progress++
           if (progress <= 100) {
               remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.play,"$progress%")
               remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.play,View.VISIBLE)
               remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.playIcon,View.GONE)
               handler.postDelayed(this, 1000) // 1000ms = 1 second
           } else {
               progress = 0 // Reset progress to 0
               remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.play,"")
               remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.play,View.GONE)
               remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.playIcon,View.VISIBLE)
               rippleBackground!!.stopRippleAnimation()
           }
       }
   }
}



This is how it shows on my screen as a widget


